# php,autoresize image is working. but it stored in local, i want to save in separate folder

Tags: php, html, mysql

this is my  code after resized the image is directly stored in local folder.i have     change into specified folder.

```
    function imagecrop($img_name,$newname,$type,$modwidth,$modheight)
    {

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_name) ; //get width & height in array         list

    $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight); 
if(!strcmp("image/png",$type))
{
imagealphablending($tn, false); //For transparent BackGround
imagesavealpha($tn, true);  
}



   if(!strcmp("image/jpg",$type) || !strcmp("image/jpeg",$type) || !strcmp("image/pjpeg",$type))
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);

    if(!strcmp("image/png",$type))
    $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($img_name);

    if(!strcmp("image/gif",$type))
        $src_img=imagecreatefromgif($img_name);

      imagecopyresampled($tn, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 


       if(!strcmp("image/png",$type))  
       {
   imagesavealpha($src_img, true);
   $ok=imagepng($tn,$newname);
       }
   else if(!strcmp("image/gif",$type))  
       {
   $ok=imagegif($tn,$newname);
   }
       else 
   {
       $ok=imagejpeg($tn,$newname);
   }

    if($ok==1)
  {
    return "<img src=".$_FILES['userfile']['name']." border='0'>";
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give path of new image when saving it. Try following code

```
function imagecrop($img_name,$newname,$type,$modwidth,$modheight)
{

    $newname = "/home/public_html/images/$newname"; //just an example


    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_name) ; //get width & height in array         list

    $tn = imagecreatetruecolor($modwidth, $modheight); 
    if(!strcmp("image/png",$type))
    {
       imagealphablending($tn, false); //For transparent BackGround
       imagesavealpha($tn, true);  
    }



   if(!strcmp("image/jpg",$type) || !strcmp("image/jpeg",$type) || !strcmp("image/pjpeg",$type))
    $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img_name);

    if(!strcmp("image/png",$type))
    $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($img_name);

    if(!strcmp("image/gif",$type))
        $src_img=imagecreatefromgif($img_name);

      imagecopyresampled($tn, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $modwidth, $modheight, $width, $height) ; 


       if(!strcmp("image/png",$type))  
       {
   imagesavealpha($src_img, true);
   $ok=imagepng($tn,$newname);
       }
   else if(!strcmp("image/gif",$type))  
       {
   $ok=imagegif($tn,$newname);
   }
       else 
   {
       $ok=imagejpeg($tn,$newname);
   }

    if($ok==1)
  {
    return "<img src=".$_FILES['userfile']['name']." border='0'>";
  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your target path in the second argument of your output image functions (imagepng, imagegif, imagejpeg). From the PHP manual:

> **filename** - The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw
>   image stream will be outputted directly.